# Way to hide the side-pane in Shotwell Photo Manager?

Tags: shotwell

The side-pane in Shotwell takes up a lot of space. And it will only let users drag it bigger, not smaller.

But ultimately, since I only interact with the side-pane once and a while, it would be preferable to be able to hide it completely. Once hidden, I would like to be able to tap F3 as a shortcut key to unhide it.

Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is currently under development. Check out [here](http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/4043)

```
Status: Open    
Start date: 08/29/2011
Priority:   Normal  
Due date:   ???
```

Comment: That ticket is for showing/hiding individual items in the sidebar, not the entire sidebar itself.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this in Shotwell today.  However, it's the kind of feature we'd certainly consider adding if you (or someone else!) would like to write a patch.

Answer (score 0):

This was recently fixed and will be available in the upcoming release of Shotwell 0.14: http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/5346

Answer (score 0):

This is possible since Shotwell 0.14.

Two ways:

- F9 is the shortcut to hide/show the side bar.
- You can also use View - Sidebar

Source (target version for feature): https://web.archive.org/web/20121008005733/http://redmine.yorba.org/issues/5346